# Why does it take hours or even days to turn on (or power up) the large, powerful superconducting magnet in an MRI machine or fusion reactor?

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, plasma-physics, fusion

Sorry I can't (yet) provide any links, but I have read in the past that turning on an MRI machine from scratch can take many hours, even days, because of the time it takes to get the powerful superconducting magnet up to full strength....

More recently, the 'New Yorker' magazine had a feature story on Commonwealth Fusion Systems (CFS) record-breaking new magnet that they are hoping to use in their upcoming fusion reactor, and said it took several days to power it up....

Why?

Comment: I wonder if what the journalist called "power up" included the time needed to cool the magnet down to liquid helium temperature.

Comment: In addition to the time spent cooling, I believe there are also enormous currents needed for these magnets, and because of induction you can't immediately ramp these currents up from zero ("nature abhors a change in flux"). In other words, if you think of it as an RL circuit, the time constant $L/R$ is huge for a big inductor. I don't know if this is a dominant time cost or not though.

Answer (score 7):

A superconducting magnet is a large inductor and holds a strong magnetic field which carries energy.

Energy must be put into the magnetic field in order to bring it up to strength.

The rate at which energy can be put into a superconducting magnet is limited, because a high rate of energy input can cause heating, which can cause the material to cease superconducting (since superconduction occurs at low temperature). This causes an undesired runaway [quenching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet#Magnet_quench) effect.

To avoid quenching, the rate of energy input is limited, which means you have to wait longer to bring the superconductor up to its desired field strength.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know the mechanism? How does a high rate of change of current or magnetic flux cause heating when a steady high current or strong magnetic flux does not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current I believe the physical underlying phenomena are eddy currents but that's a good question I am not sure about.